# Getting UnicodeDecodeError while saving numpy array to csv file

Tags: python, csv, numpy, export-to-csv

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Final_3.py", line 42, in <module>
    np.savetxt("table.csv", output_arr, fmt='%s' , delimiter=",")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1381, in savetxt
    fh.write(v)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1291, in write_normal
    self.fh.write(asunicode(v))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/compat/py3k.py", line 70, in asunicode
    return str(s).decode('ascii')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have also tried
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8') in my code, but it still didn't help.

Comment: Can you also post the code that saves to CSV?

Comment: What's the dtype and contents of the array?

Comment: Give us some idea of the values in `output_arr`, especially any strings that might not store with plain `ascii`.

Comment: np.savetxt("table.csv", output_arr, fmt='%s' , delimiter=",")

Comment: In each row of the numpy array output_arr contains 5 strings

Comment: Try adding the `encoding` parameter (in newer numpy versions).

Answer (score 0):

A `UnicodeDecodeError` occurs when Python is trying to convert Unicode into bytes. Python 2 will do this implicitly under certain circumstances, Python 3 won't. Your error messages indicate you're using Python 2.7.

It's quite possible that your problems would go away if you used Unicode strings consistently:

```
np.savetxt(u"table.csv", output_arr, fmt=u'%s' , delimiter=u",")
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the parameters. Until recently, even in Py3, `savetxt` converted unicode parameters to bytestrings.  I think the decoding problem is with the data.  Prior to version 1.14, `savetxt` tried to write everything as bytes (or 'Latin1').

Comment: @hpaulj in that case maybe the best course is to encode the strings yourself before `savetxt` has to deal with them.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Final_3.py", line 43, in <module>
    np.savetxt(u"table.csv", output_arr, fmt=u"%s" , delimiter=u",", encoding = 'utf-8')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1361, in savetxt
    raise ValueError('invalid fmt: %r' % (fmt,))
ValueError: invalid fmt: u'%s'

Answer (score 0):

I have numpy installed with Py3, so can't directly test your code.  But the error traceback looks like it is using version 1.14, the same as I am.  So this should be relevant:

Make an array with that `0xce` problem character:

```
In [553]: arr = np.array(['abc','def',chr(0xce)*3])
In [554]: arr
Out[554]: array(['abc', 'def', 'ÎÎÎ'], dtype='<U3')
```

Trying to save with an `ascii` encoding, gives a similar message:

```
In [555]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr,fmt='%s',encoding='ascii')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-555-c52f408b633c> in <module>()
----> 1 np.savetxt('test.txt',arr,fmt='%s',encoding='ascii')

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments, encoding)
   1374                                     "format specifier ('%s')"
   1375                                     % (str(X.dtype), format))
-> 1376                 fh.write(v)
   1377 
   1378         if len(footer) > 0:

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Changing the encoding works:

```
In [556]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr,fmt='%s',encoding='utf8')
In [557]: cat test.txt
abc
def
ÎÎÎ
```